# Gracefully shutdown a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

In an application I'm developing, I have a main form that simply sits there and displays log data, and a worker thread that autonomously does the work in a loop.

```
MyWorker worker = new MyWorker();
MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();

// Subscribe form to log event so log data gets displayed
worker.Log += mainForm.Log;

// Start the worker thread's MainLoop
new Thread(new ThreadStart(worker.MainLoop)).Start();

// Show the form (blocking)
Application.Run(mainForm);

// If we end up here, the form has been closed and the worker has to stop running            
worker.Running = false;
```

As you can see, whenever the form is closed, the worker thread should be stopped. The worker looks like this:

```
public class MyWorker
{
    public String Running { get; set; }

    public MyWorker()
    {
        Running = true;
    }

    public void MainLoop()
    {

        while (Running)
        {

            DoExtensiveWork1();
            if (!Running) return;

            DoExtensiveWork2();
            if (!Running) return;

            DoExtensiveWork3();
            if (!Running) return;

            DoExtensiveWork4();
            if (!Running) return;

            DoExtensiveWork5();         
            if (!Running) return;

            // We have to wait fifteen minutes (900 seconds) 
            // before another "run" can be processed
            for (int i = 0; i < 900; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                if (!Running) return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want the thread to be able to stop when switching between successive work operations, but not when within an operation. When an operation (`DoExtensiveWorkN`) has finished, its status and results are persisted do disk or database, so quitting while an operation is in progress (by, for example, `Thread.Abort`) is not an option.

However, I find this code I've just written repulsive to look at, especially the "wait loop" which sleeps for one second 900 times, to prevent the thread from idling for 15 minutes before detecting `Running` has been set to `false`.

I'd rather be able to throw some kind of event to stop the main loop as soon as it's finished a piece of work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction how to do this, or if a total rewrite is required because I totally misunderstood threading, show me somewhere where those principles are explained?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can tidy up both the running of the individual tasks and the 15 min wait loop considerably.

I'd suggest perhaps using something like this:

```
public class MyWorker
{
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _stopEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private readonly Action[] _workUnits;

    private bool Running
    {
        get { return !_stopEvent.WaitOne(0); }
    }

    public MyWorker()
    {
        _workUnits = new Action[]
        {
            DoExtensiveWork1,
            DoExtensiveWork2,
            DoExtensiveWork3,
            DoExtensiveWork4,
            DoExtensiveWork5
        };
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _stopEvent.Set();
    }

    public void MainLoop()
    {

        while (Running)
        {
            foreach (var workUnit in _workUnits)
            {
                workUnit();
                if (!Running) return;
            }           

            // We have to wait fifteen minutes (900 seconds) 
            // before another "run" can be processed
            if (_stopEvent.WaitOne(900000)) return;
        }
    }
}
```

Then to stop the process at the next appropriate point:

```
Worker.Stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx).

You can do your work with the running thing and rather than using the sleep you can just set the timer to go off again in 15 minutes.

If you want to stop it early then call some kind of abort method (similar to setting your Running=true variable) that will stop the timer.

It should be noted that each time the timer event fires it will start up a new thread so you dont' need to worry about killing background threads. Your thread finishes its run of processing, sets the timer to run in 15 minutes and then the thread finishes naturally. If you abort during a wait then you just get rid of the timer and no more cleanup needed. If you abort during a run then you let the run finish and at the end it checks a flag and doesn't start the timer again and then the thread finishes.

For the timer you'll want to set the timer to start manually at the end of the process. The alternative is to have the timer ticking every 15 minutes but that would mean that if your processing took 10 minutes then it owuld only be 5 minutes before the next run. And if it took more than 15 minutes you may be in trouble. Also restarting the timer manually guarantees that the processing shouldn't restart while another is running.

Comment: Timers won't solve the main problem I'm having: I don't want the work to continue when the form is closed, and I don't want to add a lot of code to keep checking for that.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Ah, I misunderstood "so quitting while an operation is in progress (by, for example, Thread.Abort) is not an option" to meant the entire thread. My thought then would be using an array of Actions but Iridium beat me to it. I still prefer the timer for the 15 minute wait though. :)

Comment: I could've described that more clearly. Thanks for the suggestion though. :-)